# How do I query a quite deeply nested object in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection with multiple documents with this format:

```
{
    "id" : "65451735",
    "recommendations" : [ 
        {
            "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2018-12-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "products" : [ 
                {
                    "productName" : "name1",
                    "productId" : "productid1"           
                }, 
                {
                    "productName" : "name2",
                    "productId" : "productid1"
                }
            ],
            "recommendationsValueGlobal" : 0.0
        }
    ]
}
```

I have with filter with "id" and "productId".

**There's 2 issues regarding the productId:**

**1.- it can accept comma separated values of multiple product ids**

**2.- the productId is really deeply nested, I've never searched through an object this deep in the document. There can be multiple recommendations, and multiple products**

I need to return all documents where id matches and only include any of the products that have the Ids given, all other should not be displayed.

**I know how to search on nested object inside an array, but this is way too much, specially with comma separated values. Any suggestion?**

EDIT: Also the Id is not unique and can be repeated in multiple documents

Comment: If you don't mind using some library, like lodash, maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610948/lodash-find-deep-in-array-of-object) can help you.

Comment: Create a view grouping the "id"s together since its not unique then query your view with the productid